# Access data in DynamoDb from multiple regions in one go

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Say, I have a AWS dynamodb table in 4 regions. Now, if I want to find some entry in that dynamoDB from AWS console UI, do I need to go to each region and then find? Or is there a way which would do a search in all regions in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're not referring to a replicated Global Table but instead ypu actually have 4 distinct tables in 4 regions that happen to have the same name.

If that is the case, you can't query, or even access the distinct tables in the same query. This is not possible because the tables are actually distinct from the stand poinr of DynamoDB and multi-table operations are not possible.

You may issue separate queries, one for each table, or create a replicated Global Table if you would like the data in the different regions to be replicated.